# Remove unused cordova plugins

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I'm developing ionic app using cordova plugins.
I don't want to remove one by one.
How to remove unused plugins from ionic 3 project?

Comment: i think ionic is not come up with any of the command than you seek for you should manually remove the plugin that you don't want

Answer (score 1):

you can do it one single command, install the cli plugin below

```
npm install -g cordova-check-plugins
```

it is a kind of plugin manager, now you can ply with it.

```
cordova-check-plugins --remove-all
```

above command will delete all your plugin installed in your project.

if you are not able to run the above command then try the command

```
cordova-check-plugins --remove-all -save
```

Now when you build the project or add the platform it will automatically install all required plugins.

thank you

Comment: does it mean this command automatically remove all import line from all code pages??

Comment: The asker iasking how to remove ununsed plugins not all plugins, this plugin does not do that.